# getting 'DataFrameGroupBy' object is not callable in jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby

I have this csv file from https://www.data.gov.au/dataset/airport-traffic-data/resource/f0fbdc3d-1a82-4671-956f-7fee3bf9d7f2

I'm trying to aggregate with

```
airportdata = Airports.groupby(['Year_Ended_December'])('Dom_Pax_in','Dom_Pax_Out')
airportdata.sum()
```

However, I keep getting `'DataFrameGroupBy'` object is not callable
and it wont print the data I want
How to fix the issue?

Comment: Format your question properly please

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the `sum` aggregation before extracting the columns:

`airportdata_agg = Airports.groupby(['Year_Ended_December']).sum()[['Dom_Pax_in','Dom_Pax_Out']]`

Alternatively, if you'd like to ensure you're not aggregating columns you are not going to use:

`airportdata_agg = Airports[['Dom_Pax_in','Dom_Pax_Out', 'Year_Ended_December']].groupby(['Year_Ended_December']).sum()`